# JSON string and PERL

Tags: json, perl

How can I read a JSON string like this without "headers":

```
[{"SMS":"hello","NUM":12345},{"SMS":"bye","NUM":54321}]
```

```
my $json = JSON->new->utf8;
my $perl_data = $json->decode($content);
print ref($perl_data) . "\n";
```

returns ARRAY. I would like each element.

Thanks

Comment: Iterate over it. Your JSON has an array. So has your Perl. There are no headers of any kind there.

Comment: using

my $json = JSON->new->utf8;
                my @perl_data = $json->decode($content);

                foreach (@perl_data){
                        print "$_\n";
                }

return ARRAY(0xae699d0)

Comment: That code you just commented will not work. You'll have the same array reference inside of `@perl_data` as the first element. And then you'll get something like `ARRAY(0x1234567)` as the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an array ref around the hash references. You need to iterate over the array reference to get each element.

```
use Data::Dumper;

foreach my $elem (@{ $perl_data }) {
    print Dumper $elem;
}
```

Comment: Wow! And if I'd like to access the single element?

Comment: @user476918 inside the `for()` loop: `print "$elem->{SMS}: $elem->{NUM}\n";`

Comment: @user476918 I think you are lacking some basic Perl knowledge. You should read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html for a start.